# I need help understanding what is AwsCustomResource.policy in cdk?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am using CDK's AwsCustomResource to create an S3 object.
I fail to understand AwsCustomResource.policy.
The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html) say:

> policy (mandatory): The policy to apply to the resource.

and about role:

> role (optional): The execution role for the Lambda function implementing this custom resource provider.

When I set a role, and I check the lambda of the custom resource, then I see that it got the permissions from the role, just like the docs say.

I found out that when I set the policy (values just for testing), e.g like so:

```
policy = AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_statements(statements=[PolicyStatement(actions=["s3:ReplicateTags"], resources=["*"])])
```

Then I also get this on the lambda permissions. 
This wasn't how I read the docs, I expected the policy to be used to set a policy to the resource I created, the s3 object. but what would that mean? I created the object in a pre-existing bucket, with an existing policy on the bucket. 
do s3 objects have their policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do s3 objects have their policy?

No, they do not. Only buckets have policies.

> I expected the policy to be used to set a policy to the resource I created, the s3 object.

This would be difficult as many resources do not have a resource-based policies. Such as S3 objects.

`AwsCustomResourcePolicy`  adds policies to the **execution role** of lambda function, not the resource created by the custom resource. Note that custom resources do not need to create any resources anyway.

Comment: thank you, all make sense now. would you say then that there's a documentation bug? it says for policy - "The policy to apply to the resource."

Comment: @RoyCa Maybe. It can be confusing for a novice.

Comment: just adding that the docs no longer say that, I updated it so now it's clearer: "The policy that will be added to the execution role of the Lambda function implementing this custom resource provider."

Comment: @RoyCa Thanks for letting me know.